# Crop background of the layout

Tags: android, image, layout, background, angle

I would like to make this kind of background

[image]

I tried to get this with corner radius, but unsuccessfully. What do I need to use, to cut it like this? or to even make this kind of background:

[image]

Comment: let me guess.... a png file?

Comment: yes, but I would not like to use png file, I would like to make it by shapes or something, so it would be proper to all resoliutions

Comment: Simply said: **You can't**. Shapes are **RECTANGULAR** (with rounded variations - to the extreme variation of a circle)

Comment: So no other wayt only to use image with high enough resoliution?

Comment: Exactly. Make a 480 dpi BIG big picture and use that one in the drawables-xhdpi folder. If Android won't find the minor resolution pictures, it will scale that one **DOWN** (scaling down is better than scaling up, for AntiAliasing)

Comment: Thank you Der Golem, I would accept your answer, but user184994 was first to post, so a big thank you from me, to you :) And have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create it as a .png file, and set the transparency to something less than 100% (probably about 70%), then add it to your drawable folder. In your XML file, you call then write `android:background="@drawable/your_back_image"`

Android will automatically strech it for you so it will always fit the screen.

Comment: you mena there is not other way to create it with shapes by yourselve? Because if I would use it on tablet it would require much better quality image.

Comment: You can create the image at different sizes, and store them in the correct folders, i.e. make a large one and store it in drawable--xxhdpi and Android will take of choosing which copy to use